# Show an object's rating with letsrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a music album review site, where the user posts album reviews (pins), and will select 1-5 stars to display on the show page. I'm using the letsrate gem and it works fine to input the stars on the form when submitting the new pin and editing. Now I need to display that input on the show page.

When I have `<%= @pin.rates %>` on the show page, it displays this:
`[#<Rate id: 8, rater_id: 1, rateable_id: 36, rateable_type: "Pin", stars: 4.0, dimension: nil, created_at: "2013-08-19 22:28:36", updated_at: "2013-08-19 22:28:36">]`

I need to get that stars: 4.0 to display the four stars. (and not allow them to be edited in the show view)

This is my rate model:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :pin

  attr_accessible :rate, :dimension

end
```

I saw this question posted, but it doesn't explain much about how to use the helper:
[Displaying Individual User Ratings (letsrate gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901713/displaying-individual-user-ratings-letsrate-gem)

If I use `<%= rating_for @pin =>`, then the stars show up, but anyone can rerate them, which would not be good. I need to disable them.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<%= @pin.rates[:stars].to_i %>
```

Comment: Stars is an undefined method, which I don't understand. When I use the console I've tried to pull out just the stars # and I get the undefined method there too. When I post:` <%= rating_for @pin, "Rating" %>` it does show the stars, but they are still ratable. I need them disabled.

Comment: After searching some more I see that there has been a disable_after_rate option added. They say to add it to the rating_for helper, but I don't see a rating_for helper anywhere in the helper files or elsewhere.

Comment: Does anybody have a suggestion for star ratings? I've tried to get a few gems to work, but they're all so old and unsupported its tough to find good documentation.